# Can you replicate a user share using the Graph API so that post aggregtion works?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to be able to achieve a similar effect using the Graph API to what happens when a user Shares, i.e.  you get aggregation on the share, so that if multiple users or pages share the same post you don't see the post multiple times in a newsfeed.

I can't see how to do this.  You can create a new post and post that to /feed, but that doesn't trigger aggregation, and is not what I want.  I've experimented with posting a link to the original, i.e. /page_id/posts/post_id, but that doesn't do it.

I've seen a couple of questions like this, but no clear answers.  Has anyone managed to do this?